# Cannot compile parquet-tools

Tags: java, hadoop, compiler-errors, parquet

I cloned the repository of `parquet-mr` from [this link](http://git%20clone%20https://github.com/Parquet/parquet-mr.git). The I wanted to build `parquet-tools` as explained [here](http://www.openkb.info/2015/02/how-to-build-and-use-parquet-tools-to.html):

```
cd parquet-mr/parquet-tools/
mvn clean package -Plocal
```

(I updated `pom.xml` to point correct version of `com.twitter:parquet-hadoop:jar`)

This is the compilation error that I get:

> [ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :
>   [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
>    [ERROR]    /usr/local/parquet-mr-master/parquet-tools/src/main/java/org/apache/parquet/tools/command/MergeCommand.java:[76,13]
>   cannot find symbol   symbol:   method
>   appendFile(org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration,org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path)
>   location: variable writer of type
>   org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileWriter
>    [ERROR] 
>   /usr/local/parquet-mr-master/parquet-tools/src/main/java/org/apache/parquet/tools/command/MergeCommand.java:[82,29]
>   cannot find symbol   symbol:   method
>   mergeMetadataFiles(java.util.List,org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration)
>   location: class org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileWriter

Comment: If you need a compiled version why you don't get it from apache? http://parquet.apache.org/downloads/

Answer (score 9):

Try checking out a concrete tag in git first.

```
git checkout apache-parquet-1.9.0
cd parquet-mr/parquet-tools/
mvn clean package -Plocal
```

By doing the `git checkout`, all the `pom.xml` files will say `<version>1.9.0</version>` instead of `<version>1.9.0-SNAPSHOT</version>`.